# File reading and writing it to another file

Tags: perl, file

Hi i am trying to implement the configuration file using the [`Config::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::Simple).
As i able to parse the input and write the parameters to the file.
My config file is

new.conf

```
[Section1]
param1=value1
param2=value2

[Section2]
param1=value1
param2=value2

[Section3]
param1=value1
param2=value2
```

Further i want to make a seperate sectionwise file i.e. in the above case i want to create the 3 files(because there are 3 sections)
In the first file i would want some like this

section1.conf

```
[Section1]
param1=value1
param2=value2
```

In the second file 
section2.conf

```
[Section2]
param1=value1
param2=value2
```

..so on

I guess first i want parse the particular sections and those respective parameter and then write it to the new file. Please correct me if i am 
thinking wrong.

The files should be created dynamically because file structure may vary after every form submission.

I am breaking my head to do this please suggest me how to do.

My code:

```
use Config::Simple;
$cfg = new Config::Simple(syntax=>'ini');
if($ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} eq 'POST')
{
    &myReadParse(); 
    my $cfg = Config::Simple->import_from('new.conf', \my %config) or die Config::Simple->error();      
    my %write_config= %config;      
    foreach my $config_var (sort keys %write_config) 
    {
        foreach  my $form_var ( @form_input )
        {
            local ($key, $value) = split(/=/, $form_var );
            $key =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g; 
            $value =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
            if ($config_var eq $key) 
            {
                $cfg->param($config_var, $value);
            }                   
        }       
    }
    $cfg->write("new.conf");    
}
```

Any help that will appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: yeah but i can read whole file and write but it cant cant able to write the sections seperately

Comment: This is a CGI script which seems to be using code that was already cargo-cult back in 1999. `&myReadParse()` which seems to store CGI parameters in global variables likely contains more security holes than you can count. Just so you know, there are modules to do this kind of thing. See [CGI](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI), [CGI::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Simple) etc. So, create a new `Config::Simple` object for each section, and save that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `Config::Tiny` instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Config::Tiny;
use Storable qw( dclone );

my $conf = Config::Tiny->read('new.conf');

for my $section (sort keys %$conf) {

    # Make a Deep Copy of the Config::Tiny object
    my $copy = dclone($conf);

    # Delete all the other sections
    delete $copy->{$_} for (grep { $section ne $_ } keys %$conf);

    # Write out section to new file
    my $new_conf = lc($section) . '.conf';
    $copy->write( $new_conf );

}
```

Which produces:

*section1.conf*

```
[Section1]
param1=value1
param2=value2
```

*section2.conf*

```
[Section2]
param1=value1
param2=value2
```

*section3.conf*

```
[Section3]
param1=value1
param2=value2
```

Here is another version using `Config::Simple`.  Here we need to go into the guts of the Config::Simple object, which is inelegant.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Config::Simple;
use Storable qw( dclone );

my $conf = Config::Simple->import_from('new.conf');
my @sections = keys %{$conf->{_DATA}};

for my $section ( @sections ) {

    # Make a Deep Copy of the Config::Simple object
    my $copy = dclone($conf);

    # Delete all the other sections
    delete $copy->{_DATA}->{$_} for (grep { $section ne $_ } @sections);

    # Write out section to new file
    my $new_conf = lc($section) . '.conf';
    $copy->write( $new_conf );

}
```

Which produces section files like this:

*section1.conf*

```
; Config::Simple 4.58
; Mon Aug 10 21:13:43 2015

[Section1]
param2=value2
param1=value1
```

Comment: is it possible to do in Config::simple because as of now i cant to some other module??

Comment: from the above code in my post i can able to store all sections with there parameters in one file..how can i store it for separate file for separate section??

Comment: Before you call $cfg->write in your code, you can iterate over the sections, and split them out into separate files, as is shown above.

Comment: another favor if u dont mind...how can i store it in different path?? how can i change it i this code?? my $new_conf = lc($section) . '.conf';

Comment: $new_conf = '/some/other/place/' . lc($section) . '.conf';